# Why did Harry think that James Potter was such a great guy?

Tags: harry-potter

All of the flashbacks and memories that involve James potter seem to show him as a quite self-centered bully, a sneak, and a rebel.

Is there anything in the books that show James to be the really swell guy that Harry built up in his head?

The only information he would have had prior to attending Hogwarts would be from home, and there certainly wasn't any positive input there.

Edit:  Sorry, the original question is less about what Harry thought about his father and more about whether Harry's views actually matched the man.

Comment: Yes, he was an utter tool when he was younger. In his later years, he devoted himself to fighting Voldemort and ended up sacrificing his life for the betterment of Wizardkind. The question is really whether the two cancel each other out.

Comment: Perhaps the fact that he was eventually named Head Boy, as explained in [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/83148/42121).

Comment: Part of why Lily eventually fell for him is that he grew up. He was very immature and self-obsessed and sometimes cruel, but he did what we all do eventually and just grew up a bit.

Comment: Did  Luke think his Jedi Dad was hip before that whole treachery debacle?

Comment: Considering the source of his information at home I would be surprised if Harry took it at face value.  I would expect that he would form a visualization of his parents that was completely different to what he was being told by his aunt and uncle.

Comment: why would he *not* think highly of his Dad? Don't we all love our parents unless given reason to feel otherwise?

Comment: @Richard  Was he fighting Voldemort because it was the right thing to do, or because Voldemort had targeted his son and family?  His sacrifice was less for the betterment of Wizardkind and more desperately trying to save himself and his family.

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister - Feelings of intense hatred towards a parent who died in combat is a very common occurrence. The fact that they valued the Army (or whichever Service) over caring for their children can lead to feelings of abandonment and long-term attachment issues. It's far from certain that a parent who died will be viewed positively.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson - James Potter and Lily Potter took a conscious decision not to simply refuse to serve Voldemort but to actively oppose him. Other wizards simply went into hiding, presumably with some success.

Comment: @Richard personally, I don't think you can equate the Potters to army veterans. As for choosing it "over caring for their children"... Harry has no reason to think that whatsoever, as Lily and James *literally died protecting Harry*. Whether they could or could not have avoid the conflict is another issue, but everyone - including Harry himself - seems to be agreed on the fact that the Order were working to protect all that was good in the wizarding world. A noble cause and one that was perfectly understandable to Harry.

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister - I'm not saying that the two things are directly comparable, obviously they aren't but I've met enough orphans to know that not all of them idolise their deceased parents.

Comment: It would certainly not be hard to understand if Harry found himself looking at his parents' pictures and saying "You should have just kept your heads down!" Possibly with a good deal of anger.

Comment: @Richard is that orphans, or specifically military orphans? Obviously while he is living with the Dursleys, Harry thinks his parents died in a car crash. Whatever he learns about them from the Dursleys he has every reason to not trust. And by the time he learns otherwise, people like Hagrid are telling him how good his parents were. He doesn't really get any hint that James had a "bad side" until we see the way he treated Snape. 
Ultimately, not sure why we are having this discussion as I think your answer below is a good one.

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister - It's especially true of the orphans of those who've died 'in service'. In the UK that's far more likely to be military than police.

Comment: @Richard I just don't see how that relates to Harry's situation. He never really has time to internalise the idea that he was "abandoned" by military vet parents. For a long time he thinks they were car crash victims. Then he learns otherwise, and any disappointment he might have felt over how they died is *immediately* tempered by tales of how great his parents were and how important it was that Voldemort was stopped.

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister - I'll accept that. There's not much by way of introspection from Harry's perspective in the books.

Comment: James ***was not*** a nice guy. That's the whole raison d'etre of the books.  Superficially James was the "lovable scamp" type. The reality was he stole Lily from her actual true love, and was pointlessly cruel and shallow. Simply, James was the "jock/bully" type - nothing more than that. The entire point of the whole amazing work of literature is about coming to terms with the fact that a hero-worshipped father is actually a prick. That the union which created you was not a genuine eternal love match (like Snape and Lily) but nothing more than the "high-school jock showing off" type of match.

Comment: @JoeBlow - I'd take exception to the idea that James *stole* Lily from Snape. If I've learned anything about modern feminism it's that women rarely like being viewed as objects to be possessed.

Comment: Harry was also an utter tool when young, so there's that.

Comment: @JoeBlow *The reality was he stole Lily from her actual true love* Um, what? No. Lily eventually grew to like him after ditching a negging, possessive creep who demanded a free pass on insulting her heritage.

Comment: related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13052/wasnt-harrys-father-just-like-draco?rq=1

Answer (score 51, accepted):

By the end of Philosopher's Stone, Harry knows quite a few things about James that are likely to have endeared him.

**Hagrid liked him** (see also, [why Harry hates Slytherin](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/94247/20774))

> ‘Sorry,’ he said. ‘But it’s that sad – knew yer mum an’ dad, an’ nicer
>   people yeh couldn’t find – anyway –

**He left Harry a pile of money**

> All Harry’s – it was incredible. The Dursleys couldn’t have known
>   about this or they’d have had it from him faster than blinking. How
>   often had they complained how much Harry cost them to keep? And all
>   the time there had been a small fortune belonging to him, buried deep
>   under London.

**He was an impressive Quidditch player**

> ‘Your father would have been proud,’ she said. ‘He was an excellent
>   Quidditch player himself.’

**He hated Snape.**

> ‘Oh, he does,’ said Quirrell casually, ‘heavens, yes. He was at
>   Hogwarts with your father, didn’t you know? They loathed each other.

**His father looks a lot like him**

> The tall, thin, black-haired man standing next to her put his arm around her. He wore glasses, and his hair was very untidy. It stuck up at the back, just like Harry’s did.

**He died (bravely) defending Harry and Lily**

> ‘How touching …’ it hissed. ‘I always value bravery … Yes, boy, your
>   parents were brave … I killed your father first and he put up a
>   courageous fight … but your mother needn’t have died … she was trying
>   to protect you … Now give me the Stone, unless you want her to have
>   died in vain.’

**He was a lovable scamp**

> Dumbledore’s eyes twinkled. ‘Useful things … your father used it
>   mainly for sneaking off to the kitchens to steal food when he was
>   here.’

**James Potter put his life on the block to save an enemy**

> ‘Well, they did rather detest each other. Not unlike yourself and Mr Malfoy. And then, your father did something Snape could never forgive.’
>   ‘What?’
>   ‘He saved his life.’

Comment: And you didn't list "being named Head Boy", which I think I get.  As someone looking in on the English (British?) school system from the outside (books and such) being named Head Boy would hardly be something that would "enamour him" to another boy.  But that's just my impression: that Head Boys are pompous ambitious bum kissers (as seen by other boys).  Is that the way it really is, though?

Comment: It's really quite notable that Harry didn't really get a view of James Potter from Snape's perspective until much much later on.

Comment: @davidbak - I can't find anything in any of the books to suggest that Harry Potter was especially impressed by someone (whether his father, Voldemort or Percy) being Head Boy or Head Girl. There are some mentions, but that's about it.

Comment: No, I don't recall anything like that.  Mrs Weasley, yes, of course.  But Harry, no.  I was just asking (in a comment, it's not worth a question) whether, in general, English (British?) boys would consider the Head Boy a role model, or not?  Something to aspire to themselves?  (The boys themselves, not their parents.)

Comment: Snape is mean to harry, so Harry hates Snape. Harry learns James hated Snape, so he likes that, but would Snape have chosen to be so mean to Harry if James hadn't bullied and abused him as a student? Hmmm.... so really Harry should resent James for indirectly contributing to his suffering.

Comment: @davidbak - In my experience it depends on the school, the student and the head boy himself. Generally I think a previously popular head boy would only benefit from it, while a head boy like Percy would be treated, well, like Percy by most of the students. Also some schools are much better than others at building school pride etc.

Comment: @davidbak: James Potter was Head Boy – is that from Pottermore or whence? All I knew is, he, like Sirius, was _not_ a prefect (“I spent too much time in detention with James. Lupin was the good guy, he got the badge”). ... **oh,** I see [it's discussed in this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83145/how-did-james-potter-become-the-head-boy/83148#83148); forget it; _Hagrid_ tells Harry that James was Head Boy.

Comment: "He saved his life"  I believe when Harry confronted Snape's with that bit of information, it was revealed that the only reason Snape's life was in danger was directly because of James.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson - Yeah, but he doesn't find out until much later, long after he's decided that his dad was an amazing guy.

Answer (score 30):

I think the answer is simply:

**James is Harry's Dad**

All children (by default) look up to their parents. Even when kids start to rebel against their parents, it's often simply due to a desire of the child to develop an identity of their own. Barring extreme circumstances, a child always has a level of love and respect for their parents.

Additionally, as a child gets older, children may "lose" some respect for their parents (or alternatively, get a different understanding of their personality) due to behaviors of the parent (in my mind, I'm viewing it as the classic-teenager "Dad, you're embarrassing me" mantra). Harry, however, never had any 'negative' interactions with his parents (and as Richard's answer pointed out, he only heard positive reports about his parents. Which frankly, makes sense, because it would be really inappropriate to put down a kids' dead parents in front of him). The only people who denigrated his parents were, frankly, people Harry didn't care too much about.

This is why in Book 5, when Harry was in the memories of his father in Snape's pensieve, it had a particularly strong effect on him. This was the first time he saw his father in a bad (arguably very bad) light, and it was something that was 'real' in the sense that it was an actual event that happened, and not a biased accounting from enemies of the Potters.

Comment: I think this might be a bit too simplistic. There are plenty of people who [don't like their parents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lizzie_Borden) and their absence could easily have resulted in his *disliking* them, especially as they chose to put their own lives at risk rather than care for him.

Comment: I don't think this applies as far as the biological parents in an adopted kid situation - or rather why would this apply to James and not Vernon?

Answer (score 11):

There is a lot of [confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias) going on in Harry's head. Obviously he wants his father to have been a great guy, because that's so much nicer than having an nasty, inconsequential nobody for a father. So everything positive he hears (quidditch seeker, head boy etc) reinforces the mental image, and anything negative (James and Snape loathed each other, James stealing food) is interpreted in the most positive way possible. It doesn't help that most of the people around him who knew James don't want to pop his bubble.

Only when Harry is confronted with Snape's memory of James and the other Marauders at their most vicious does he start to re-evaluate his image of his father.

Answer (score 1):

All of the memories we see are from Snape’s prospective and they did not like each other... at all. So, it’s not a fair representation of James. Other people who describe James loved him, they admitted he had faults, but every character did because they were meant to. But every single other character in the books had nothing but good things to say about James Potter.

This is what we know about James:
He was a spoiled, only child to elderly, wealthy parents. Well loved, but probably rarely heard “no.” 
He found out his friend and dorm mate was a werewolf; instead of outing him, rejecting him, and acting like basically the rest of wizarding society (he was progressive 
and obviously valued equality) he became and animagus at an extraordinary young age all to help his friend. 
He saved Snapes life. Whether he was trying to keep out of trouble, or protect Remus, or maybe he just valued human life... he still did it, which is brave. 
He took in Sirius when his parents kicked him out and provided for him financially. 
His last action on earth, was going up against the most powerful dark wizard, wandless, knowing he was about to die, all to buy time for his wife and child to run.

What we know about Lily:
She was uncommonly kind and she called him out on his actions. She was smart, brave, loving, steadfastly held to her principles. She was probably the first person ever in James’ life to go toe-to-toe with him. Parents, teachers, peers and friends worshiped the ground he walked on because he was brilliant, but I think were unwilling to call him out. I would have a big head, too. Give him a little slack, he was 15. Then Lily comes waltzing up and rips him down. I think seeing her reaction to his antics really opened his eyes and he changed his behavior. Do you the Lily Evans we saw, would marry a bully.? No I don’t think so. And by the photographs we have of him and Lily, I’d say they were very much in love. I don’t think Lily would love a cruel man.

Answer (score -1):

And of course Harry had no conscious memory of James, so would find it easy to idealise him. There's and old saying "it's far easier to be a royalist if you don't have to work with the royals close up."